# For loop isn't working in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to save a file from a URL into a folder on my computer, but I have 732 URLs (that when saved, gives experimental data) in a list.  I'm trying to run a `for loop` on all those URLs to save each data set into its own file. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
for i in ExperimentURLs:
    myurl123 = str(i)
    myreq = urllib.request.urlopen(myurl123)    
    mydata = myreq.read()
    with open('/Users/lauren/Desktop/IDData/file', 'wb') as ofile:
        ofile.write(mydata)
```

`ExperimentURLs` is my list of URLs, but I don't know how to handle the `for loop` to save each data set into a new file. Currently, this code only writes a single experiment's data into a file and stops there. If I try to save it to a different file name, it takes a different experiment's data and saves that to the file.  Help?

Comment: you might need to append to a file instead of writing, https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is simply at the point of writing the files. Not that the for loop is not working. You are writing to the same file again and again. Here is a modified version, using requests. All you need to do is simply change the file name when saving.

```
import requests

ExperimentURLs = [
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.yahoo.com"
]

counter = 0;
for i in ExperimentURLs:
    myurl123 = str(i)
    r = requests.get(myurl123)
    mydata = r.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    fileName = counter
    with open("results/"+str(fileName)+".html", 'w') as ofile:
        ofile.write(mydata)
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to automatically generate a new output file name every time through the loop.  I'll give you the trivial version below.  Also, note that the URLs are already strings; you don't have to convert them.

```
pos = 0
for myurl123 in ExperimentURLs:
    myreq = urllib.request.urlopen(myurl123)    
    mydata = myreq.read()
    out_file = '/Users/lauren/Desktop/IDData/file' + str(pos)
    with open(out_file, 'wb') as ofile:
        ofile.write(mydata)
    pos += 1
```

Does that solve your problem?

BTW, you can do the two iterations in parallel with

```
for i, myurl123 in enumerate(ExperimentURLs):
```

Comment: Yes that works, thank you very much! What does the two iterations in parallel mean?

Comment: The new `for` statement handles both iterators (`i` and `myurl123`) at the same time.

Comment: I'm wondering if for loops works then if I'm now trying to put all these .txt files into individual dataframes?

Comment: Currently using this code: randomdf = pd.read_csv("/Users/lauren/Desktop/IDData/file0",sep='\t',
                 header = None)

Comment: Yes, individual DFs should work as well as individual text files.